# wp-android Error in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, wordpress, styles

I was Downloaded the WordPress-Android Package in http://github.com
and I was follow the Built Instructions to develop my own project.
here, i got some error that was appear at the root I was mentioned below..

wp-android/res/values/styles.xml

wp-android/res/values-v11/styles.xml

wp-android/res/values-v14/styles.xml

These 3 files got error so, i can't to run the project..
Please, Give solution to run the project Successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean the project and than run again